# Javascript regex for numbers, symbols and white space

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have the following regex to validate a field including only numbers.

```
/^\s*\d+\s*$/
```

This works fine for numbers e.g. 15544447777 or any other length of numbers

But I also need to validate combinations such as these :

```
11232-23423-1223235-11
```

or

```
12312 23423235235  123123
```

Basically just use regex to match any combination of numbers, symbols and white spaces. I've looked over a lot of threads but every one of them seems to be 'fixed' on a certain length of numbers. I need to be able to verify any length.

Can someone help me out here with such a regex.

Thanks

Comment: so you want to avoid just letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
^[^a-zA-Z]+$
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nH2gW1/2)

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  [^a-zA-Z]+               any character except: 
                            'a' to 'z', 
                            'A' to 'Z' 
                            (1 or more times )
  $                        the end of the string
```

Comment: This allows for non-English characters (`åäöëš` etc.)

Comment: Works great, but I forgot to ask, is it possible to restrict the symbols to - only?

Comment: There are two things either add the character that is not expected or just add the expected one. just change in `^[^...]$` into `^[...]$` to make it opposite. For example `^[0-9\s-]+$` to match only digits, white spaces and hyphen.

Comment: Sorry I'm totally a noob at regex but I couldn't get the above regex to allow only the - dash symbol and no other symbols

Comment: ^\s*[\d\- ]+\s*$ use this

Comment: @vks what about other special characters and symbols?

Comment: You can check my ans for that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
        ^\s*[\d\-\(\)\[\]{} ]+\s*$
```

This should do it.

Comment: Doesn't allow for `()[]<>` etc.

Comment: in question it is mentioned that "match any combination of numbers, symbols and white spaces".Why should we allow ()[] etc.?How can they be part of telephone number?

Comment: The question does not define "symbols". And some people write phone numbers like `(123) 4567890`.

Comment: just added some symbols as suggested by Pietu1998.To include cases like (123) 4567890